# Is it possible to use a custom Region controller in DXA 1.7?

Tags: dxa, dxa-1.7

Is it possible to override the default Region controller in DXA 1.7

Looking at the `RegionController` in [Github](https://github.com/sdl/dxa-web-application-dotnet/blob/release/1.7/Sdl.Web.Mvc/Controllers/RegionController.cs) it is decorated with `HandleSectionError` attribute to handle exceptions.
I try to bypass that handler and handle those exception in the Page model instead.

I try to create my custom `RegionController` like this:

```
public class RegionController : Sdl.Web.Mvc.Controllers.RegionController
{
    public override ActionResult Region(RegionModel region, int containerSize = 0)
    {
        // Do custom stuff here
        return base.Region(region, containerSize);
    }
}
```

And register in the area registration like this:

```
// My own region controller should be use
RegisterViewModel("MyRegionName", typeof(RegionModel), "RegionController");
```

But still seems to be using the default one.

Answer (score 1):

Custom Region Controllers are currently unfortunately not supported in DXA.